# 1 dimension nesting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nested-loops

I have a problem with creating a nesting loop for 1 dimension. Let say I have an enough number of 7m length bars and I want to cut it as 3 x 2m , 4 x 3m, 1 x 4m and 2 x 5m with minimum wastage. can anybody help me to develop algorithm for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a the optimization problem for [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), where you are looking to find the closest (yet smaller) number that you can reach with your elements, to the target.

This problem in general is NP-Complete, but there is [pseudo-polynomial solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) to it that if fairly efficient for relatively small integers.

The solution is based on building a table `d` of `n*W` dimenstions (`n` is the number of elements and `W` is the target number), and use the following recursive formula:

```
f(0,i) = true
f(x,0) = false  for all x != 0
f(x,i) = f(x-arr[i],i-1) OR f(x,i-1)
```

The target number you are looking for is the greatest number `x` such that `f(x,n) = true` and `x<=W`.

Finding the elements you chose can be done by "remembering" each choice - did you take it or not to the set.

Comment: Doesn't this solve the problem only for one single bar? He asked to split multiple bars with minimal wastage.

Comment: @ruediste From my understanding of the question, you have a bar of length 7m, and you want to 'split' it to smaller bars with little wastage as possible, where the valid splits are 3x2m, 4x3m, 1x4m, 2x5m. So you have an array [2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5] and you want to find elements that sum to 7, in this example. Maybe I misunderstood the OP's intention?

Comment: Oh, I understood it different: There is a given set of bar lengths and a pile of 7m bars. The task is do determine how to cut the 7m bars to get the desired splits with minimal wastage (that is, using the minimal number of 7m bars). @user3178876: which version do you need?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Bin Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). From the description:

> In the bin packing problem, objects of different volumes must be packed into a finite number of bins or containers each of volume V in a way that minimizes the number of bins used.

Start with the wikipedia article linked above to find an algorithm.